How to draw a set of multiple lines, with slight angles in GIMP?
I'm trying to draw a set of multiple lines, almost parallel but also angled, something like the image attached. I'm trying to recreate something like this image with GIMP.


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Personally, I wouldn't use GIMP for this kind of work. It's easier to do using a vector image editor. Inkscape (which is free and open source) is a vector image editor which has all the tools to do this built-in.  GIMP is great software, but it's mainly a photo editor - and sure it can be done in GIMP with the use of a script as shown in the accepted answer, but Inkscape is designed for work exactly like this.

With the ofn-path-rungs script(*):
You create paths where the lines "bounce" (you can have path lines outside the canvas):

You call the script (probably "By count" option, using the same count each time):

The script will generate "count" lines between the two paths:

You repeat the process for each pair of paths:

You can make all the results a single path using Merge visible paths
in the Paths list

You then render the path, for instance here: Edit > Stroke path with a 3px thick line and the foreground color set to a dark green:

(*) installation instructions at the bottom of the linked page. ZIP contains a HTML doc.
